# Is there a reverse df.melt() function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking to achieve the following result.
I want this DataFrame:

```
elem |node 
a    |1
a    |2
b    |3
b    |4
```

to become

```
elem |node_x |node_y
a    |1      |2
b    |3      |4
```

this is basically `df.pivot(index='elem', values='node')` but without specifying any columns Series.

The following code does what I want:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'elem': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 'node' : [1,2,3,4]}) 
df1 = df.groupby('elem').idxmax() 
df2 = df.groupby('elem').idxmin() 
join = df1.merge(df2, how='inner', on='elem')
```

But I was wondering if there was a better way to do this in a single step with Pandas function.